# How to ng-repeat multiple properties?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have taken the example from Angular documentation into a Plunker for a quick demonstration of what I am trying to do. What I have is a name and lastName as part of an object in array. When I start to filter the input, it works well until I start to type the lastName after I have typed the name. How would I go about having it so that the search results would include the name and the lastName? I have been stumped on this and can't get past figuring this out so I am looking for a little help.

```
<div ng-controller="repeatController">
  I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
  <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter friends..." aria-label="filter friends" />

  <ul class="example-animate-container">
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length === 0">
      <strong>No results found...</strong>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/SS2X2ZmguxNxQ4Txz3BN

Thank you in advance for any help given.

*EDIT*: What I am looking for is that if I was to type John Doe, the result would not say "No results found". It works fine if I am typing in one property, but once I start to do the lastName, there are no results found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the lastName, you can do the exact same thing as you're doing with both the friend's `name` and `age`.

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} {{friend.lastName}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
</li>
```

I've updated your plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/gocfrflA6VKUDBwBcYKK?p=preview

Edit: As you're also interested to search over a combination of multiple fields, you need to implement a custom filter function.

```
$scope.search = function (friend) {
  var fullName = friend.name + ' ' + friend.lastName;
  return !$scope.q || fullName.indexOf($scope.q) !== -1;
};
```

and

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: search">
```

I've created a plunkr for this aswell: https://plnkr.co/edit/fr3XH3ghMw0hidceXDVx?p=preview

An even better approach would be to make use of a custom filter.
Be sure to read: 
https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/ and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: Yes but the problem is that if you type John Doe, it says there are no results?

Comment: That's because the search is only searching for a single property. Your question didn't include anything related to searching both `name` and `lastName`.

Comment: Here is the plunkr to search both, I'll update my answer: https://plnkr.co/edit/fr3XH3ghMw0hidceXDVx?p=preview

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you for hanging in there and helping me out. Sorry about the original confusion.

Answer (score -1):

In another approach I'd like to modify the list which I'm iterating, `friends` in your case.

```
<input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter friends..." aria-label="filter friends" />
<ul class="example-animate-container">

    <!-- instead of using the list directly I'd like to call a function which would return me the filtered list, hence getFriends()-->

    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in getFriends()">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="getFriends().length === 0">
      <strong>No results found...</strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now in my controller I'd implement the function as following-

```
$scope.$watch('q', function () {    
  $scope.getFriends = function(){
    var friends = $scope.friends;

    var params;

    if( $scope.q.indexOf(' ') > -1 ){
      var q = $scope.q.split(" ");
      params = {
        name: q[0],
        lastName: q[1]
      };
    }
    else{
      params = $scope.q;
    }

    // You can modify params for even more powerful filter... if you need actually...

    return $filter("filter")(friends, params);
  }
}
```

I use this approach so that I've full access to the filter right in my controller. Most of the cases I need this type of customised filter not more than once, so I'd rather put them in my controller.

One tiny glitch though, you need to define `$scope.q` somewhere in the controller, otherwise it'd through a `Reference Error`

https://plnkr.co/edit/7FTgkXOtldihFBy7cuSP?p=preview

**UPDATE**

@FrederikPrijck guided me through a great example about how to eliminate calling this function in every digest cycle. I've updated my answer reflecting that. *Another thing* is I use this approach when I need very extensive control to my filter like you don't have room for multiple input field but you need to filter by multiple properties, or sometimes I needed to update the list based on `$broadcast`. If you need to use a simple filter like this question, please use the accepted answer.

Comment: This looks interesting. Between this and the one that I chose for the answer - just wanted to learn more - what is the difference? Is there a performance gain of any type? Best practice?

Comment: Well to be honest both of the answers are almost same to each other. Ih the answer you accepted filter was implemented in the view, I just took it away in the controller. I just want my view to be as clean as possible. View is for view only, this is best practice, where you should put your business logic in your controller. Although this entirely depends on yourself.

Comment: Using a filter in a controller isn't a bad thing(it can even have a better performance impact if implemented correctly), but the above answer does not describe a correct way to implement that imho. Generally a filter get's moved to the controller to avoid running it on every digest. Using this approach still triggers the filter on every digest cycle. Basicly you want to trigger the filter only if whatever drives the filter is changed using a `$watch` for example.
Leaving that aside, I don't think adding 16 LOC to replace a single, super simple, filter in html is to be considered "clean".

Comment: I've created a plunkr to demonstrate how you could avoid executing it on every digest cycle but still move the logic to the controller: https://plnkr.co/edit/M95Z2CHz9W6myy0RnAF1?p=preview

Note: I prefer my answer unless performance get's in the way.

Comment: @FrederikPrijck thank you for your valuable comment. I didn't have the digest cycle in my mind actually. I'd definitely use this in my projects now on..

Comment: @maksbd19A reply to your edited answer: If you need a complex filter, write a custom filter. Not just some function in your controller.

Comment: @FrederikPrijck should I write custom filter even if I needed that just once?

Answer (score -1):

```
        **Hey i have changed json object of $scope.friends**
     I have added one more key **fullName** now it will search on fullName

            angular.forEach($scope.friends,function(value,key)
           {
             value['fullName'] = value.name +" " + value.lastName;
            })
```